# need that one ngfor refill all datas on lists of html

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying charge in my pages all data from a json databases, the problem is this charge is good until I include new data, which appear in the Array (I see it with a console.log) and created the row but don't refill this row, and show me empty.

I tried to made if, and put:
if is this row write me: hello
and this show me in the page, but when i put: `nombres_indicadores[i][0]`
don't show me the data.

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of indicadores; let i = index">
    <td *ngIf="nombres_capitulo[i] != ''" 
       [rowSpan]="nombres_capitulo[i][1]">
       <b>{{nombres_capitulo[i][0]}}</b>                   
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>{{nombres_indicadores[i][0]}}</p>
    </td>

    <td>
        {{nombres_indicadores[i][1]}}
    </td>
```

Comment: try adding `changeDetectionRef.detectChanges()` after the new assignment.

Comment: {{nombres_capitulo[i] | json}} You can try printing this, this can help you debug